# Unity: How do I generate multiple different random numbers in the same frame?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, random

I'm attempting to generate a random vector3 by generating the x, y and z components individually (afaik there is no way to generate a random vector3 outright).

I have  this part working fine;

I create the seed `Random.seed = DateTime.Now.Ticks` etc

I then generate the random numbers;

```
float x = Random.Range(-10000, 10000);
float y = Random.Range(-10000, 10000);
float z = Random.Range(-10000, 10000);
```

I then have some code that will check to ensure that this vector generated is unique.

The issue lies in that, because this is happening in the same frame, the x, y and z values are allthe same.

For example, if the random generator generates x = -1402.345, then y and z also shall be -1402.345.

I have attempted to put this generation into a coroutine which would solve the issue (by yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame etc) however when I want to then check these values and if need be regenerate them, I cannot without starting a new coroutine . Seeing as these vectors are also being saved to a database, where I want to generate hundreds (possibly thousands) of data entries, starting a new coroutine each time the generated vector is invalid is impractical and will likely just end up breaking my program.

Is there a simpler way to generate 3 random numbers in the same frame? I had considered simply changing the seed, but am unsure if this is good practice or if there is a better way?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the seed isn't being reset before each call to Random.Range?

Comment: I have run your code, and it generates different values in same frame. Do you set seed every time after generating random number?

Comment: Unity is using system time to seed random function so if all Random.Range called in same time then the results will be same.

Comment: you are **completely wrong**, Neo.  it is 100% certain that the Random.Range function works perfectly.  you've simply made some trivial mistake in your code.

Comment: ***do not under any circumstances use the seed function***.  simply delete that line of code.

Comment: @JoeBlow why is it bad to use the seed function at all? I can understand using it multiple times, however using the seed function to reproduce "random" results I can see as beneficial - for instance recreating a minecraft world from the seed, inputting a value would allow multiple users to play the same world.

Comment: Hey @NeoKuro, if you're using the "Seed" function you've simply seen ancient example code, 15-20 years out of date, it's just too silly to discuss.  you might as well be asking **how do I blit in sprites in Unity??**, heh, it's completely silly.

Comment: {regarding the obscure idea of using a seed to generate the "same" results from testing: that is an incredibly out-of-date idea, and it is in practice unusable these days.  any non-trivial unity project will continually call for random numbers in 100s of different "random" ways, it's inconceivable a real-life "run" will be the same based on a seed.}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the random numbers do not have to be reproducible, just don't provide a seed, then alle numbers generated are "random".

Then you can use it just the way you tried:

```
float x = Random.Range(-10000, 10000);
float y = Random.Range(-10000, 10000);
float z = Random.Range(-10000, 10000);
```

Comment: correct.   ***Never, ever, ever*** use the seed functions.